# Why does a while loop not work to wait for AlertDialog input

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

My question is about Android/Java.

I want to program a method in which I want to return a string from an input field of an AlertDialog. The AlertDialog runs asynchronously and does not wait until the user clicks on OK.

My method:

```
public String prompt(String title){
        final StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();
        final AtomicBoolean closed = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(title);

// Set up the input
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        builder.setView(input);

// Set up the buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    value.append(input.getText().toString());
                    closed.set(true);
                }
            });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

        builder.show();
        while(closed.get() == false){
            
        }
        return value.toString();
    }
```

How I call the method:

```
String sentence = prompt("Give me a sentence: ").toLowerCase();
```

The problem is that the dialog doesn't appear at all. And I don't understand. After the dialog should appear, a while loop follows. This is to prevent the method from returning a value until the user clicks OK. But it doesn't happen that way...

So why doesn't work a while loop for waiting a user to click on OK at an AlertDialog? And how can I solve this problem?

***You could write:***

**The dialog doesn't appear because the main thread is stuck in the while loop. You can't hold the main thread using a while loop, the app will go to [ANR state](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr).**

***My answer:***

*I thought the whole thing would run asynchronously. The main thread should quietly get stuck in the while loop, but at the same time it should asynchronously do what it should be doing. Why is the whole main thread stuck when it should actually run asynchronously?*

Comment: You've made this problem yourself by wrongly implementing Alert Dialogs.  "The AlertDialog runs asynchronously" that's not how this works on android.

Comment: You have code after .show(). The dialog will only show if all code after show() is done.

Answer (score 0):

Before showing dialog you need to create something like this:

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

then,

```
dialog.show();
```